# Question about seeing watch with hands in a mirror

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reflection, geometry

What will be the time shown in a watch or clock, if we see it in the mirror?

Assuming I have a watch with hands (analog and having no numbers) showing time 2:37. What will be the time if I see it in a mirror?

Such questions can be easily answered by looking in a mirror.  But if I try to answer this type of questions without looking in a mirror, I always get wrong answers as I am bad at imagination.

And furthermore, mirrors will not be provided in exams. Can someone please suggest an easy way to do this without involving much imagination.

Comment: You could try  making a drawing, the mirror will switch left to right

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following trick.

The magnitude of speed of watches hands in the mirror is the same as the of the hands of "real" watches. But the direction is different: the hands rotate counterclockwise in the mirror.

Start experiment in 0:00:00. Both watches show this time. But now hands of real watches started to move forward, and the hands of "mirror" watches started to move backward with the same speed. In 2 hours 37 minutes the mirror watches will display 0:00 - 2:37 = 9:23

Comment: Thank u very much. It is a very good method. So that means whatever the question is given I just have to subtract it from 12:00

Answer (score 0):

It's commonly stated that plane mirrors reverse the image's left and right sides. But why don't they then reverse top and bottom as well?

What the plane mirror actually does is reverse front and back. Stand with your clock between yourself and the mirror. Look at the back of the clock. Now imagine a computer graphic effect where the front of the clock is pulled straight back through the clock to become visible to you. This is rather like reaching down to the toe of a sock and pulling it through the the opening to evert it.

One way you know this is, from your view behind the clock, the face of the real clock is farther than the back of the clock. But in the mirror, the image of the face appears closer to you than the image of the back.

Comment: Thanks, but it  involves a lot of imagination.